# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.ITestNGMethod.getConstructorOrMethod()Lorg/testng/internal/ConstructorOrMethod;

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, testng

I'm trying to run the unit tests but I'm getting the following error.

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\skakani\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.2\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.ITestNGMethod.getConstructorOrMethod()Lorg/testng/internal/ConstructorOrMethod;
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEATestNGRemoteListener$DelegatedResult.calculateDisplayName(IDEATestNGRemoteListener.java:379)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEATestNGRemoteListener$DelegatedResult.<init>(IDEATestNGRemoteListener.java:369)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEATestNGRemoteListener.createDelegated(IDEATestNGRemoteListener.java:354)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEATestNGRemoteListener.onTestFailure(IDEATestNGRemoteListener.java:112)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEATestNGTestListener.onTestFailure(IDEATestNGTestListener.java:27)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1796)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1780)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1230)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:964)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

The temp-testng-customsuite.xml has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="od">
    <classes>
      <class name="services.job.KafkaMessagesTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- od -->
</suite> <!-- Default Suite -->
```

My maven dependencies for testng are as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using Java 8 and Intellij Community IDE if that matters. Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: some possibilities: 1. there's a typo in the method name 2. you've passed wrong parameter(s) 3. You have a conflict in dependencies -> several versions of that class, and it takes the wrong one

Comment: also try to update to recent testng (>= 7.0.0) and IDEA, and change maven scope to test

Comment: @Stultuske 1. There's no typo. I checked and everything seems correct. 2. Even the simple print statements aren't working, so the possibility of wrong parameters isn't true. 3. I just have one version of testng, so there isn't any conflict that I could find.

Comment: @quickfix: I tried with testng >= 7.0.0 but it didn't help either.

Comment: how did you verify there's only one version of that library? Either way, in version 6.0, that method indeed didn't exist. It's possible you have a mismatch somewhere, that you still have the version 6 (or similar) somewhere through another dependency

Comment: @Stultuske I checked in my .m2 folder as well as in `Project Structure` in IntelliJ.

Comment: @ShrikantKakani which isn't sufficient. you may very well have a second dependency through another dependency. Try and execute a mvn dependency:tree